# Can someone currently transit from the UK through France (unvaccinated)?

Tags: uk, france, covid-19

I have reviewed the 'reasons for travel' document to enter France from the UK and can see the bottom option is 'transit in less than 24 hours'.

I plan to get the Eurotunnel to Calais and then drive to Italy in under 24 hours, will I be permitted to travel using that option (unvaccinated, with negative covid test and other documents, etc.)

Comment: What's your citizenship and place of residence? If you are resident of Italy it should be possible. Otherwise, it probably won't, the "transit in less than 24 hours" for people not transiting to their EU country of residence is under the condition you stay airside (in the "international zone" of airports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, if you don't have an essential reason.

> According to the newly announced measures, all unvaccinated or not fully vaccinated travellers entering France from the UK will now only be allowed to enter the country for essential purposes and will be obliged to present a negative COVID-19 test result carried out within 24 hours before entry.

[Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/france-announces-stricter-restrictions-against-non-vaccinated-travellers-from-uk-spain-portugal/)

Comment: There's quite an extensive list of essential reasons, including transit, but with conditions.

Comment: In the words of Bill Clinton, "it depends on what the definition of 'is' is." In this case, it depends on the definition of transit. If transit is landing at an airport, staying in the International section and boarding another plane, flying away, or if entering via the Eurotunnel and driving all the way through France, stopping for lunch, petrol, etc counts as 'transit'.

Comment: @CGCampbell unfortunately, it does state the transit must be in an international zone. I wanted to get trains to Italy....